# I can't find any problem in this code (reverse string )

Tags: python

this program must reverse String

I can't find any problem here, I test this program and this is okay for any test case
I use but when I uploaded this program in especial site (I can't access test case)
some test cases don't correct

```
n = input()
m = ''
i = -1

while (len(n) - 1) > len(m):
    while -i < len(n) + 1:
        j=1
        while j > 0:
            m += n[i]
            j -= 2
            i -= 1
print(m)
```

Comment: Can you share the test case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access the test case

Comment: Your program is working properly for me.

Comment: for me to, this really simple program, but because I can't access the test case I can't find out what's problem here

Comment: works here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ too, can you share the non working test case with us ?

Comment: So I did find a problem: I ran your code, with `n` being `1` (as a string), and at the end `m` was simply nothing.

Comment: Go https://www.online-python.com/xXJM9apB4I.

Comment: If you run it you will find nothing is being printed; however, if I add a letter to it, both the letter and the number are shown.

Comment: If I enter the string `x`, should I not get the revered string being `x`? (cause I don't)

Comment: I think I found the problem; your program with any string with the length of 1 character will return nothing.

Comment: so if len(n) > 1 then , else n=m ?

Comment: Why is that `while j` loop in there?  Doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix it (as far as I tried):

```
def reverse(n):
    m=''
    i=-1
    while (len(n))>len(m) :
      while -i<len(n)+1 :
        j=1
        while j>0  :
            m+=n[i]    
            j-=2
        i-=1
    return m
```

Your problem was in the first `while` loop. You did: `while (len(n)-1) > len(m):`, but that `-1` was not supposed to be there.

Otherwise one-character strings would have a length of 1, and 1 - 1 = 0 (that extra -1 would make the length 0). So `len(n)-1` would have been 0.

Since the length of `m` was also 0, the code in the `while` loop would never execute (because 0 is not bigger than 0), and thus an empty string (`m`) would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could just slice backwards:

```
text = "Hello World"
print(text[::-1])
```

see  [Extended slicing in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices)

Comment: They are asking about their own program, not another way to do it.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich sure. But a major part of learning any language is learning the built in functions. I'd take a one liner over a big ol triple nested while loop any day of the week.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the question asks about their specific program.